# In windows, can the right click context menu be altered to only Paste?

Tags: windows, contextmenu, copy-paste, paste, right-click

I'm not sure if this is possible, but can the context menu in windows that appears when you right click be removed and just have it perform one function.  For example... if I right click over an input I see a menu with options: undo,cut,copy,paste,delete.  I want no menu to appear and right click to do one thing only, PASTE.  I don't want to choose paste from a menu, just do it instantly when I right click.

Comment: If you are referring to the Window Explorer context menu, you can [remove it completely](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc975944.aspx) and use Ctrl+V to paste.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](https://superuser.com/q/5011/52365)

Comment: I don't want to ctlr+v though.  In my situation, I don't really want to use the keyboard at all and I want to make it as easy as possible, just a right-click and it's done.  If that's not possible, the next best thing would be to program a single key to do the paste.  Like, making the F1 key be a paste key.

Comment: You could grab a USB button then ([e.g.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=StealthSwitch&tbm=isch)), program it to Paste and provide it to the user instead of the keyboard...

Comment: There is no such thing as the right-click context menu. Every application decides what to do in response to a right-click, based on the window underneath the mouse pointer. So instead of showing a menu, simply paste the clipboard contents.